# Excel - Find & Replace Part of String But in Same Cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have

```
Column A

Red-US
Blue-INT
Purple-INT
White-US-CA
```

Trying remove `-us, int, ca, etc.`

So it's just `Red, Blue, Purple, etc.`

Can't use Trim or Substitute formula because I want it to change directly in Column A (replace)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "-" is a consistent separator then it should be pretty simple.

Here are some commands you could use:

[Strings and Manipulations](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~tplacek/courses/3600/Strings%20and%20Manipulations.htm)

**Edit:** Added simple code

```
Sub textuptodash()
    i = 1 'start on row 1
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) 'do until cell is empty
        If Not InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "-") = 0 Then 'if dash in cell
            Cells(i, 1) = Left(Cells(i, 1), InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "-") - 1) 'change cell contents
        End If
        i = i + 1 'increment row
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Split` as follows:

```
Sub MySplit()

    Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngCell As Range
    Dim strTemp() As String, strDel As String, strTest As String
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Set rngMyRange = Range("A1:A4")

    For Each rngCell In rngMyRange
        ' Split the test based on the delimiter
        ' Store entries in a vector of strings
        strTemp = Split(rngCell.Text, "-")
        ' Reset cell value and intermmediate delimiter
        rngCell.Value = vbNullString
        strDel = vbNullString
        ' Scan all entries. store all of them but not the last -* part
        For lngCnt = LBound(strTemp) To UBound(strTemp) - 1
            rngCell = rngCell & strDel & strTemp(lngCnt)
            ' If we enter the loop again we will need to apend a "-"
            strDel = "-"
        Next lngCnt
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Red
Blue
Purple
White-US
```

It is not entirely clear how you want the last entry to be split: assumed that you want to remove the last "-*" bit only. To keep the first part only, comment out the `For lngCnt` loop.

I hope this helps!